# asp/sql multiple record sets record not found

Tags: sql, asp-classic, recordset

I'm not experienced with ASP or SQL, but have been given the task of recreating/improving a tool for my organization. The tool searches availability for two products, based on zip code. I need to search two tables, using separate queries, and display two sets of results.
(The tables each contain a column called "zip" that needs to be handled separately, so I wasn't able to use a join.)

It looks like I've successfully created the the two record sets and, in most cases, I'm receiving results for both queries. Where I'm running into an issues is when no records are found for the first query, the second doesn't seem to run.

Here is the code for handling results from the first query:

```
if ors.EOF then
response.write("not found")

else if ors("flag") = 1 then
response.write("flag is 1")

elseif ors("flag") = 2 then
response.write("flag is 2")

elseif ors("flag") = 3 then
response.write("flag is 3")

else
response.write("something else")

end if
```

And here is the code for the second:

```
if ors2.EOF then
response.write("not found")

else
response.write("found")

end if
```

It must have something to do with the "if ors.EOF then" statement, but I can't figure out how to work around it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post more of your code -- I don't see any obvious mistakes with the above code except the "else if" which I assume was a copy past error?

Comment: Nope, that was an actual typo and fixing it solved the issue. Thank you so much for spotting that!

Comment: I've posted the answer below -- best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code above, could your if / else if logic be incorrect?  When there are no records from your first query, are you seeing anything printed from your 2nd?  It might be possible your code is compiling as such:

```
if ors.EOF then
   response.write("not found")
else 
   if ors("flag") = 1 then
      response.write("flag is 1")
   elseif ors("flag") = 2 then
      response.write("flag is 2")
   elseif ors("flag") = 3 then
      response.write("flag is 3")
   else
      response.write("something else")
   end if

   if ors2.EOF then
      response.write("not found")
   else
      response.write("found")
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad you fixed your problem, might I suggest a case statement over the if else statements :)

```
if ors.EOF then
  response.write "not found"
else
  select case ors("flag")
    case 1,2,3 : response.write "flag is " & ors("flag")
    case else  : response.write "something else"
  end select
end if

if ors2.EOF then response.write "not found" else response.write "found"
```